# Which functional unit does the 'jl' instruction use?

Tags: assembly, x86, integer, low-level, processor

A pentium processor has several functional units which can process instructions in parallel. For example a 'load' might be happening at the same time as an 'add'. These instructions use different functional units: the load and integer.

The imull, incl, addl, cmpl all use the integer functional unit, does the 'JL' instruction use it as well?

Comment: Depends on the exact type of Pentium. Historically there have been three architectures labeled Pentium, the classic Pentium, the PPro and the Netburst, which are completly different. For which one do you want it to know?

Comment: Then you have a wrong premise. The classic Pentium has a double 5 stage pipeline, which is not able to do instruction reordering. So there is no explicit "integer" functional unit, which you seem to assume. One of the pipelines (U) can execute any instruction, the other (V) the most common ones. AFAIR conditional branches can be executed in both pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

The "JL" instruction means "**J**ump if **L**arger". It's like the "JA" instruction, but JL is used for the comparation of signed numbers and JA is used for the comparation of unsigned numbers.